# How to get specific column after call load() in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, load

I try to show specific columns of my data after call load() , let say 'id','kd_prop_id' only. can somebody help me

```
public function show(Provinsi $provinsi)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('provinsi_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        return new ProvinsiResource($provinsi->load([])); // <-- i want show specific column here..
    }
```

right now its show all fields :

```
"data": {
        "id": 616,
        "kd_prop_id": 11,
        "kd_kab": 1102,
        "kd_dt1": "06",
        "kd_dt2": "10",
        "nama_kab": "KAB. ACEH",
        "lat": 3.3,
        "lng": 97.69,
        "kd_bast": "061300",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "deleted_at": null
        
    }
```

plase help..thanks

Comment: As you are using Gates, probably conditionals attributes are helping in your particular case. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes

Comment: `load` is for lazy eagerloading a relationship ... seems you want to restrict the fields that are used when the model is serialized or via an api resource?

Answer (score 0):

Actually my choice would be to show the fields I want in the ProvinsiResource.

But you can review for only model:

```
$company = Company::query()
  ->first();

//$company->load(['customer']); // All company columns and customer columns

$company->load([
    'customer' => function($query) {
        return $query->select(['id', 'name']);
    }
]);

$company->only(['id', 'customer_id', 'name', 'customer']); // Only specific columns in Company and Customer columns
```

If you have collection, this way could be better:

```
$companies = Company::query()
  ->get();


$companies->map(function ($company) {
    return collect($company->toArray())
        ->only(['id', 'name', 'email'])
        ->all();
});
```